# Is it correct to use the ASP.NET Role-Based Security in a standalone WPF application?

Tags: wpf, security, role-based

I have a little experience to use the ASP.NET *Role-Base* in the WinForm apps. I know how should I use it in such applications.

Now we would like to use it in a business WPF application.

- Is it OK?
- I know it's possible but is it right to do that?

**Note:** *On of the benefits is the reusablity of our security library in Web applications.*

Comment: Are you concerned about the security aspects or the technology "mismatch" aspects?  Also, how are you planning on using it from the client application -- hosting in-process on the client, communicating with a web/WCF service, or something else?

Comment: Thanks for your attention. 1) We are concerned about technology mismatch aspects more than security. 2) Our application is not SOA. It will run on a LAN and will have simple UI/Logic/SQL SERVER layers.